# Dataflow writing a pCollection of GenericRecords to Parquet files

Tags: java, apache-beam, parquet, dataflow

In apache beam step I have a PCollection of `KV<String, Iterable<KV<Long, GenericRecord>>>>`.
I want to write all the records in the iterable to the same parquet file. My code snippet is given below

```
p.apply(ParDo.of(new MapWithAvroSchemaAndConvertToGenericRecord())) // PCollection<GenericRecord>
.apply(ParDo.of(new MapKafkaGenericRecordValue(formatter, options.getFileNameDelimiter()))) //PCollection<KV<String, KV<Long, GenericRecord>>>
.apply(GroupByKey.create()) //PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<KV<Long, GenericRecord>>>>>
```

now I want to write all the Records in the Iterable in the same parquet file(derive the file name by the key of KV).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution to the problem.
at the step -

`apply(GroupByKey.create()) //PCollection<KV<String, Iterable<KV<Long, GenericRecord>>>>>`

I will apply another transform that will return only the Iterable as the output pCollection.
`.apply(ParDo.of(new GetIterable())) //PCollection>>
where key is the name of the file I have to write to.
then remaining snippet is

```
.apply(Flatten.iterables())
                .apply(
                        FileIO.<String, KV<String, GenericRecord>>writeDynamic()
                                .by((SerializableFunction<KV<String, GenericRecord>, String>) KV::getKey)
                                .via(
                                        Contextful.fn(
                                                (SerializableFunction<KV<String, GenericRecord>, GenericRecord>) KV::getValue
                                        ),
                                        ParquetIO.sink(schema)
                                                .withCompressionCodec(CompressionCodecName.SNAPPY)


                                )

                                .withTempDirectory("/tmp/temp-beam")
                                .to(options.getGCSBucketUrl())
                                .withNumShards(1)
                                .withDestinationCoder(StringUtf8Coder.of())
                )
```